# How to get rid of "Optional(...)" in my output when transferring data to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, output, option-type

Im tring to transfer the first name of the user to another view controller when a button is pressed, and have been able to do so successfully. But i have encountered the problem of seeing "Optional(first name)" in my output. How do i get rid of this?

1st View Controller :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

var userFirstName: String = ""
var userLastName = ""
var userEmail = ""
var userPassword = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AccountViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    view.endEditing(true)
}




@IBAction func createAccountBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    userFirstName = String(describing: firstName.text)
    userLastName = String(describing: lastName.text)
    userEmail = String(describing: email.text)
    userPassword = String(describing: password.text)

    print(userFirstName)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let newVC: WelcomingViewController = segue.destination as! WelcomingViewController

    newVC.userFirstName = userFirstName
```

2nd view controller :

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!

var userFirstName: String? = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    firstNameLabel.text = userFirstName!
}
```

Comment: Do you really need "userFirstName" to be an optional?

Comment: I don't need it to be an optional, but even when i dont set any of the variables as an optional the output still includes the "Optional()". Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than a solution you need to get the basic idea about the optional in Swift.

[Swift Optional](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

You can go for

1. Forced Unwrapping: Do this if you are very sure about the content. Otherwise App will crash

   ```
   firstNameLabel.text = userFirstName!
   ```
2. Optional Binding: This is more secure way

   ```
   if let firstName = userFirstName {
       firstNameLabel.text = firstName
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `if let` approach, you can use nil coalescing like this:

```
firstNameLabel.text = userFirstName ?? "n/a"
```

This provides fallback string (or empty string, if you prefer) in case the original variable is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let firstName = userFirstName {
    firstNameLabel.text = firstName
}
```

This makes sure that `userFirstName` is not nil before it is passed to your label.

**Edit**

However, one thing to notice is that unless you are specifically setting `userFirstName` to nil at some point, you don't need it to be an optional because you give it an initial value of `""`. An optional is for something that may or may not have a value, and thus needs to be treated more carefully.